# Cannot produce element right-click in react testing-library user-event v14

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library, testing-library, user-event

I'm using react-contextmenu and I was able to trigger contextmenu in v13 by following

```
userEvent.click(node, { button: 2 });
```

but after upgrading v14 I'm not able to trigger contextmenu or right-click event of an element

Tried `fireEvent.contextMenu(node)` and various ways but didn't work.

Comment: Probably to do with this https://github.com/testing-library/user-event/pull/784/. The second parameter got removed, so you now need to be clicking a button which genuinely does trigger the event you need, without that modifier. It's to force you to write better tests. What purpose did `button: 2` serve initially?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit of a longshot but try changing to the newer API:

```
  userEventuser.pointer({ keys: '[MouseRight>]', target: node })
```